# Trying to pull DataField from PivotTable using VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to pull both a column value and a data value out of a pivot table, using Excel.

```
For j = 1 To 1 'pt.RowFields(i).PivotItems.Count
    sum = pt.DataFields(2).PivotItems(j)
    Client = pt.RowFields(1).PivotItems(j)
    Sheets("InvoiceTemplate").Range("c7").Value = Client
    Sheets("InvoiceTemplate").Range("i13").Value = sum
Next
```

The Client value comes back exactly as expected. However, the sum value throws the error:

```
Unable To Get PivotItems Property from PivotField class.
```

With a PivotTable that looks like the below, I would expect results of Contoso and £60.50

```
                  net           gross

Contoso           £50.00        £60.50
Adventureworks    £100          £110.00
```

Any idea as to what I am doing wrong? By the way, I know I have a 1 TO 1 loop, but this will be modified once this is working.

Comment: So you want the column header (Client) and what else? The Grand Total for each client (column total)?

Comment: Hi, PivotTable has 3 columns AccountName|net|gross I am trying to pull Account and Gross for each account name

Comment: @DougGlancy - I get the same error with this: sum = pt.PivotFields("gross").PivotItems(j)

Comment: datafields don't have pivotitems

Comment: ok. how can I pull the data I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
Sub PrintPivotFields()
Dim pvt As Excel.PivotTable
Dim pvtAcctField As Excel.PivotField
Dim pvtNetField As Excel.PivotField
Dim pvtItem As Excel.PivotItem

Set pvt = ActiveCell.PivotTable
Set pvtAcctField = pvt.RowFields(1)
Set pvtNetField = pvt.DataFields(1)
For Each pvtItem In pvtAcctField.PivotItems
    Debug.Print pvtItem.Name
    Debug.Print Intersect(pvtItem.DataRange.EntireRow, pvtNetField.DataRange).Value
Next pvtItem
End Sub
```

I didn't refer to this [great VBA pivot table reference](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/) by Jon Peltier, but if you do you may find a better way.